# How to call onTouchEvent manually in android

Tags: android

onTouchEvent() actually occour when we touch on the screen. But I want to call this event manually without touching the screen. I want to call this method on the basis of a boolean variable  I am new in android so I don't know exactly this is possible or not.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mind explaining why you want to? There might be a better way to achieve what you are looking to do.

Comment: You can create a new `MotionEvent` by calling `MotionEvent.obtain()`. But as @Abbas said there may be a better way to do what you want.

Comment: Actually I want to control ontouchevent of android device remotely on a button press of a remote device

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

First override the onTouchEventMethod  in the activity. then you can call that method inside any function like this.

```
public void callMethod(){
 onTouchEvent(motionevent)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to *fake* a click/tap on a `View` (like a `TextView`) and that `View` has an id, you can do:

```
 findViewById(**theId**).preformClick();
```

Alternatively if you have the `View` as an object already, you can simply call:

```
 view.performClick();
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you need something like this

```
private String TAG = GestureActivity.class.getSimpleName();
float initialX, initialY;


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        int action = event.getActionMasked();

        switch (action) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                initialX = event.getX();
                initialY = event.getY();

                Log.d(TAG, "Action was DOWN");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.d(TAG, "Action was MOVE");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                float finalX = event.getX();
                float finalY = event.getY();

                Log.d(TAG, "Action was UP");

                if (initialX < finalX) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Left to Right swipe performed");
                }

                if (initialX > finalX) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Right to Left swipe performed");
                }

                if (initialY < finalY) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Up to Down swipe performed");
                }

                if (initialY > finalY) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Down to Up swipe performed");
                }

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                Log.d(TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                Log.d(TAG, "Movement occurred outside bounds of current screen element");
                break;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```